# h2|Java Column not found (but statement works elsewhere)

Tags: java, sql, h2

I want to insert data to my table, I have an insert statement (to the same table) that I use in a different method which works in one method, but returns an `JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column xyz not found;` in another.
where `xyz` is the value I want to pass into the column (not the column name).
This is the method which triggers the exception:

```
  public void btnSaveStock(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        ArrayList<Stock> stock = new ArrayList<>();
        stock.addAll(tblStock.getItems());
        stock.remove(removedStock);
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            for (int i = 0; i < stock.size(); i++) {
                String stockName = stock.get(i).getDescription();
                String stockCode = stock.get(i).getCode();
                double fuelBalance = stock.get(i).getStoresBalance();
                double counterBalance = stock.get(i).getCounterBalance();
                System.out.println(stockName + stockCode + fuelBalance + counterBalance);
                String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STOCK (CODE, description, \"fuelBalance\", \"counterBalance\") VALUES (" + stockCode + ",'New Product','1.00','1.00')";
                statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
                String updateQuery = "Update STOCK set DESCRIPTION='" + stockName + "' where CODE='" + stockCode + "'";
                statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                updateQuery = "Update STOCK set  \"fuelBalance\"='" + fuelBalance + "' where CODE='" + stockCode + "'";
                statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                updateQuery = "Update STOCK set \"counterBalance\"='" + counterBalance + "' where CODE='" + stockCode + "'";
                statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     //more method calls here
    }
```

This is the method that successfully inserts data:

```
    public void addNewStock(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        String lastCode = savedStockList.get(savedStockList.size() - 1).getCode();
        int newCode = 1 + Integer.parseInt(lastCode);
        stock.setCode(String.valueOf(newCode));
        stock.setCounterBalance(0);
        stock.setDescription("New Product");
        stock.setStoresBalance(0);
        savedStockList.add(stock);
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STOCK (CODE, description, \"fuelBalance\", \"counterBalance\") VALUES (" + newCode + ",'New Product','1.00','1.00')";
            statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        initialiseStock();
    }
```

So if `stockCode` contains the value xyz, the exception will be `Column xyz not found`

I'm failing to understand why this works in one method, but returns an exception in another.

Comment: what are the two methods you used? could you provide more details

Comment: Don't concatenate Strings. Use PreparedStatements. Your code is pretty unsafe against SQL Injection.

Comment: why you don't use a singleton class for retrieving the connection? rather than repeat yourself

Comment: Could you plz try this statement

```
 String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STOCK (CODE, description, fuelBalance, counterBalance) VALUES ('" + stockCode + "','New Product','1.00','1.00')";
 
```

, And please use PreparedStatement to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Alright, trying that. I'll change it up to prepared statements too. Thank you

Comment: @AhmadM.using the line you gave me, I get this - `SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "FUELBALANCE" not found; SQL statement:`

Comment: Let me use PreparedStatements since they are better anyways. I'd still want to know what causes the piece to work in another method but fail in another though

Answer (score 0):

It works because `newCode` is a number which doesn't need quotes and doesn't work because `stockCode` is a string and needs to be quoted. Add single quotes around `stockCode` and it should work:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STOCK (CODE, description, \"fuelBalance\", \"counterBalance\") VALUES ('" + stockCode + "','New Product','1.00','1.00')";
```

As a side note you should really use [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Oh thank you. Thats exactly it. I'm changing it up to using prepared statements